# Anylogic Problem with database import from excel

Tags: anylogic

Every time I try to import database to any logic, I get the error.
Event loop Exception.java.sql.Batch update exception. unexpected token double required.
unexpected token double required.

Any ideas how to solve this problem please?

i tried to reducing the data and changing the file i import

Comment: More details pls. What dbase, what structure, what AnyLogic dbase setup... screenshots, descriptions, anything :)